# Logging during backup or howto disable the “skipping msg with key” msg on Couchbase Server?

Tags: logging, couchbase

We are using CouchBase Server 3.X,
In one bucket we have alot of different instances of the same product running, every instance has it's own unique prefix:

```
DE1::...
US2::...
```

To get a consistent backup, we shutdown one instance and only backup the values of this instance. 
We are using the the following command:

```
cbbackup CB_HOST CB_BACKUP_DIR -u CB_ADMIN_NAME -p CB_ADMIN_PASS -b CB_BUCKET_NAME -k CB_WORLD_KEY
```

The `CB_WORLD_KEY` could be for example US2. This works fine .... but we get a lot of this logging messages:

> 2015-10-13 07:25:59,582: w1 skipping msg with key: TSO::02::190672

The bucket contains around `200 000 000` ojects and we only backup ~ `20 000 000` at a time ... so we will get `180 000 000` log messages!

Now the question: how can we avoid this log messages? We found no option for this.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to disable the logging, if using the pre-compiled file

> ../couchbase/bin/cbbackup[.exe]

... you have to use the python scripts

> ../couchbase/lib/python/cbbackup.py

Answer (score 0):

If you're set on using cbbackup, you can edit the file pump.py and comment out the line:

```
logging.warn("skipping msg with key: " + str(key))
```

Or set the logger level to ERROR.

Comment: We try this, but it seems that this not the line is which is logging ... we search "in files" with notpad++ and we found that this logging message is also inside the cbbackup binary. 

Changing the logging level has also not effect.